# std function requirements

Tags: c++, c

I could not figure out why I get the wrong mean and how I can get the std.

Comment: Related: [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random). Its whats for dinner.

Comment: This seems to be a mix of C and C++; I don't think C has namespaces or objects or headers that don't end with `.h`.

Comment: This is mostly C, but with some C++ (vector<double>, namestpace, etc).

Comment: For a finite set of numbers, the standard deviation is found by taking the square root of the average of the squared differences of the values from their average value. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation)

Comment: Yes it's mixed which is required

Comment: 1) Please correct your grammar and punctuation; it's hard to tell what your question is. 2) You want the mean of a bin? Which bin? Where in the code do you attempt to calculate it? 3) Learn loops; you've written what we call "copy-and-paste code" which is bad in several ways. 4) Don't write so much code before testing it and working out the bugs; start small and simple, add complexity a little at a time, test at every step and **never add to code that doesn't work**.

Comment: Why don't you tell us what you want your program to do?

Answer (score 2):

The standard deviation is the square root of the variance.  First you need the mean (average), of a sample set X,

```
mean = u = sum( X[0] .. x[n-1] ) / n
```

The variance is the average of the squares of the differences between each sample X(i) and the mean, u,

```
variance = sum( (x[0]-u)^2 .. (x[n-1]-u)^2 ) / n
```

And the standard deviation (std), is the square root of the variance,

```
std = sqrt( variance );
```

But you have the standard deviation calculated at the end.  Unless you mean for the 'bins' as something to do with calculating stddev for each of the counts[] buckets?

Comment: you're missing the squares in the variance.

Comment: You can calculate both mean and variance in one pass. Just keep track of both sum(x) and sum(x^2), then variance = (sum(x^2)/n) - (sum(x)/n)^2.

Comment: Please recheck that, (X-u)^2 != X^2 - u^2